# JTable info onto Jlabels

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, jlabel

How do I manage to get my information from my `JTable` and display them onto `JLabel` components that are on a different panel and not within the table itself?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: Share your code, So we can try to help unless no-one here is free for writing the entire code for you.

Comment: @Java-Dev *"Share your code"* No! It's better they post a MRE / SSCCE as advised over ten hours ago. Follow / read the links and you might understand *why* we advise that specific form of code. Note that the first link auto-expands from `[mre]`.